# Getting started with REST API from JSP

Tags: rest, jsp

I am not a programmer but have to build some demos using different programming languages as part of my job. 
I am trying to use a REST API webservice that provides an oauth token first and using this token I need to invoke another webservice. 
I don't know where to start - I have googled to look for samples in jsp but found nothing. Can I get some samples or high level guidance on how to get an access-token and use this in subsequent POST calls?

Comment: maybe duplicate [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376829/using-rest-with-jsp) or [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964055/how-to-make-a-rest-api-call-to-start-an-executable-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by just starting a new JSP project from scratch. I am able to get the OAUTH refresh token from the webservice.

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.*" %>
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONSerializer"%>

<%@page import="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;"%> 

<%

String sp_clientid="64557e87-806e-41bb-9760-acc42de3f281";
String sp_clientsecret="4c115ba5-58d8-44d0-9378-0abe9d1bb9f8";
String sp_refreshtoken="40b19430-5d83-42f6-8b27-14c9cf70b8c1";

String GRANT_TYPE = "refresh_token";
String PARAM_GRANT_TYPE = "refresh_token";

String url="https://api0.silverpop.com/oauth/token";
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
String responseText="";

PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);
post.setParameter("client_id",sp_clientid);
post.setParameter("client_secret", sp_clientsecret);
post.setParameter("refresh_token", sp_refreshtoken);
post.setParameter("grant_type",PARAM_GRANT_TYPE);

httpclient.executeMethod(post);
//responseText=getResponseText(post);
InputStream is = post.getResponseBodyAsStream();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
responseText=scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";

System.out.println(responseText);

%>



<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" media="screen" />     
</head>

<body>
        HELLO WORLD
        <TABLE BORDER="0" cellpadding="0" CELLSPACING="0" class=boldtable>
        <TR>
        <FONT size="15">
        <TD WIDTH="450" HEIGHT="600">

        </TD>


        </TR>
        </TABLE>
        </FONT>



</body>

</html>
```